# Esquema de ROTA .htaccess

Tags: html, html5, htaccess

Tenho a seguinte URL:

```
http://localhost/devops/json/index.php
```

e eu desejo que fique assim o acesso ao index dessa página:

```
http://localhost/devops/json/
```

Desejo que a exibição do `index.php` seja oculto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todas as modificações de redirecionamento e extensões de url são alteradas no arquivo .htaccess!

Abaixo segue o código!

```
RewriteEngineOn
RewriteCond%{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-f
RewriteCond%{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-d
RewriteRule^(.*)$/index.php?/$1[L]
```